# Why does DialogResult::Yes require a ::?

Tags: .net, namespaces, c++-cli, messagebox

Why does this work:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
...
if( MessageBox::Show("Really do it?", "Are you sure?", System::Windows::Forms::MessageBoxButtons::YesNo) == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::Yes )
{
    Console::WriteLine("Do it!");
}
```

..when this fails:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
...
if( MessageBox::Show("Really do it?", "Are you sure?", System::Windows::Forms::MessageBoxButtons::YesNo) == DialogResult::Yes )
{
    Console::WriteLine("Do it!");
}
```

...with the following error:

```
error C2039: 'Yes' : is not a member of 'System::Windows::Forms::Form::DialogResult'
```

I'm assuming Visual Studio is picking up DialogResult but I can't see where it's finding it?

Comment: I'm sure the answer is blindingly obvious but I can't see it...

Comment: `System::Windows::Forms::Form::DialogResult` (in the error message)? That's odd.

Comment: I should mention that the code snippets above are being called from a class which derives from `System::Windows::Forms::Form`

Comment: ...and I think that answers the question in fact - presumably `System::Windows::Forms::Form` has a `Dialog::Result` method or property and consequently it's finding that instead of the standard windows forms version?

Comment: That's what I'm thinking, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System::Windows::Forms::Form` has a property also called DialogResult (being of type `System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult`), hence the error.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx

Answer (score 3):

It's a naming collision, Form.DialogResult is a property of Form. [See here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult.aspx) I assume your code is part of a Form and thus that takes precedence.

Comment: If this is true, then the compiler or C++-CLI is pretty stupid. Ordinary C++ requires that only types and namespaces are found when looking for the name preceeding a `::`. His could would have worked then.

Comment: Given in the OP's comments above he does mention that he's deriving from ::Forms::Form, it would appear to be the case that MS have dropped the ball on that one.